# XML message signing in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

Can someone suggest is there any other possible way to signing the XML message other than using MIME/SMIME Encoder & decoder in pipeline?

I am not sure whether we can use AS2 protocol for signing XML message and FTPing the message.

Comment: It would depend on what end point you are talking to.  
If it is a AS2 endpoint that supports XML messages, then yes you can.
Other than that you can use the appropriate WCF adapters with the correct Security mode e.g. TransportWithMessageCredential, Message client credential type Certificate and the appropriate certificate configured.  Give us more details of the endpoint.

Comment: We are using FTP adapter to transmit the XML message to end point.We are in the analysis stage to find the best option to transmit the signed message to end point.In MIME/SMIME Encoder/decoder ,Encoding use 64 bit process and decoding use 32 bit process.But the end point needs the signed message transmission to be in 64 bit process

Comment: So far as I know FTP does not support AS2, AS2 is only HTTP or HTTPS.   

There is nothing stopping you using any of the many hashing algorithms out there to add a signature element to your XML payload.  

If you don't want to use the MIME/SMIME pipeline Encoder & decoder, you would either have to create your own pipeline component to do this, or sign the messages before it is sent through the port.  

The recipient would also need to know how to verify the signature.  Your question is a bit broad to give further details

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use the MIME/SMIME?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I will check with the end point on the same.

Comment: No issues using MIME/SMIME.Can you please let me know whether MIME/SMIME encoder and decoder works with 32 bit process or 64 bit process.End point suggested us to sue only 64 bit process.I do not know broad details on these pipeline component.If you know any information on this please let me know

Comment: 32 bit only I believe (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578427.aspx) also see this blog for an overview of security with BizTalk etc. https://mohamadhalabi.com/2014/07/07/biztalk-security-essentials/

Comment: Thanks for your update.Will check the link and work accordingly

Comment: End point team wants to use 64bit host instance for signing the message.Since MIME/SMIME supports only 32 bit host instance we need to find alternative options to signing the message

Comment: Why are they artificially constraining the requirements? If you are using the FTP adapter, that also requires 32bit. "Running the FTP adapter, POP3 adapter, and MIME Decoder on 64-bit host instances is not supported" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560166.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS2 is not supported on FTP, only on HTTP & HTTPS.

Using the MIME/SMIME pipeline component would be your best option.  See [How to Configure the MIME/SMIME Decoder Pipeline Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578427.aspx) and [Essential Guide to Certificates, Encryption, and Signatures](https://mohamadhalabi.com/2014/07/07/biztalk-security-essentials/)

Both the FTP adapter and the MIME/SMIME pipeline component need to run on a 32bit host.

[BizTalk Server 64-Bit Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560166.aspx)

> Running the FTP adapter, POP3 adapter, and MIME Decoder on 64-bit host instances is not supported"

Comment: Thanks the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

While MIMI/SMIME will work, it is mostly viewed as a 'web' thing.

It is much more likely that your Trading Partner will support PGP, especially if the transfer protocol is FTP.

These Pipeline Components work very well for PGP and BizTalk: [BizTalk: Sample: PGP Encryption/Decryption Pipeline Components](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/BizTalk-Sample-PGP-ebcbc8b2)

If you distribute individual keys, the data is encrypted and implicitly signed.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it all depends on what your trading partner accepts.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link.The code which they have mentioned is specific to pgp.Can we use the same code for BizTalk or any modifications to be made.BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll contains specific namesapce for pgp.Is there any such specific namespace to be used for BizTalk.Could you please advice

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the comment.

Comment: The pipeline component code link which you have shared is specific to pgp.Can we use the same code for BizTalk or any modifications we need to do to make the code usable for BizTalk

Comment: That article is for a BizTalk Pipeline Component that performs PGP so it is BizTalk code already.

Comment: Is there any existing custom pipeline component code for digitally signing the xml message in BizTalk?